# Spring Boot 2.2.4 Health Check is failing when spring.cloud.config.fail-fast = false

Tags: spring-boot, java-11

Health check failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerHealthIndicator","thread_name","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"stack_trace":"org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'configServerRetryInterceptor'

Answer (score 0):

Changing spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=false to spring.cloud.config.failFast=false will solve this issue.

Reference: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/879

Comment: Still same issue , spring.cloud.config.failFast=false is not working

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a `configServerRetryInterceptor` bean to resolve the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

```
@Bean
public RetryOperationsInterceptor configServerRetryInterceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless().build();
}
```

Reference:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#config-client-retry